# Optimizing Play Framework CI process

Tags: scala, jenkins, playframework, continuous-integration, sbt

#### Background

I'm using Jenkins to compile, test, package and deploy my Play Framework application.

Play Frameowrk Version: 2.3.8 (but is the same for 2.2.3)

Essentially there are three jobs: test, package and deploy.

1. Test is executed on each git commit, compiles the code and runs the tests using the sbt commands "clean test". If successfull..
2. The package job checks out the above commit, compiles and packages the app into a zip using the sbt commands "clean dist". If successfull..
3. The deploy job copies the zip to the target instance, unpacks it and starts the application.

In reality there are more step 2 jobs (like code coverage, checkstyle, ...)

#### Problem

The problem is, that the process is getting slow (110+ Java files / 70+ Scala (Template) files) and therefore is not as helpful as I hope it could be. Build times for the whole process is about 15 Minutes.

#### Things I tried

I discovered, that compilation time is taking up most of the build time and is executed as part of each build step.

To workaround this, I added a new job, which just compiles the project, keeps the whole jenkins worksapce as an artifact and copies it to the other jobs. But sbt keeps on recompiling the whole project in the other build jobs.

I understand that sbt uses some cache folders, which pathes I changed using the following sbt command line options:

```
-Dsbt.log.noformat=true -Dsbt.global.base=project/.sbtboot -Dsbt.boot.directory=project/.boot -Dsbt.ivy.home=project/.ivy -Dsbt.global.staging=project/.staging
```

But still sbt recompiles the whole thing.

#### Questions:

- How could I aggregate the compile phases of each job?
- Are there other cache options?
- Maybe package the compiled sources into a *.jar or simliar?
- Any other ideas for the improving the build time?

#### Thanks!

PS: of course I removed the clean command from sbt, when copying the compiled workspace

Comment: Regarding your PS: so you do have or not a clean command in each step? If so why not just clean -> compile -> test -> dist -> QA tasks?

Comment: sorry for beeing not clear: i had clean initially, but for the test with compile step i removed it for the successive jobs

Comment: for your question about putting all in one job; i would like to see the failing command just by looking at the job title; also i am not really sure if there migth be test files packaged, if there is no clean in between test and dist